# add string in each line at the begining of column

Tags: string, bash, awk

I am interested in adding a string `chr` to the beginning of column in each line.

The file is tab delimited and looks something like:

```
re1 1   AGT
re2 1   AGT
re3 2   ACGTCA
re12    3   ACGTACT
```

what I need is:

```
re1 chr1    AGT
re2 chr1    AGT
re3 chr2    ACGTCA
re12    chr3    ACGTACT
```

The solution can be a bash one-liner

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ awk '$2="chr"$2' file
re1 chr1 AGT
re2 chr1 AGT
re3 chr2 ACGTCA
re12 chr3 ACGTACT
```

#### Explanation

With `$2="chr"$2` we add `chr` to the 2nd field. Then we do not need any other command to get the desired output, as the default behaviour of awk is `print $0`.

To make sure the OFS (output field separator) is a tab, you can do the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$2="chr"$2' file
re1     chr1    AGT
re2     chr1    AGT
re3     chr2    ACGTCA
re12    chr3    ACGTACT
```

Comment: Good that it worked to you, @Irek! Remember you can mark one of the answers as accepted if your issue is already solved. Greetings

Answer (score 4):

Awk one-liner do?

```
$ awk -v OFS=$'\t' '{ $2="chr" $2; print}' so.txt
re1     chr1    AGT
re2     chr1    AGT
re3     chr2    ACGTCA
re12    chr3    ACGTACT
```

Comment: How would you do this for EVERY column after the first column. Would the code change if the number of columns varies for each row?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/chr&/' < input > output
```