# Add string to columns in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a comma-delimited file to which I want to append a string in specific columns. I am trying [to do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18061775/1379826), but couldn't do it until now.

```
re1,1,a1e,a2e,AGT
re2,2,a1w,a2w,AGT
re3,3,a1t,a2t,ACGTCA
re12,4,b1e,b2e,ACGTACT
```

And I want to append 'some_string' to columns 3 and 4:

```
re1,1,some_stringa1e,some_stringa2e,AGT
re2,2,some_stringa1w,some_stringa2w,AGT
re3,3,some_stringa1t,some_stringa2t,ACGTCA
re12,4,some_stringb1e,some_stringb2e,ACGTACT
```

I was trying something similar to the suggestion solution, but to no avail:

```
awk -v OFS=$'\,' '{ $3="some_string" $3; print}' $lookup_file
```

Also, I would like my string to be added to both columns. How would you do this with awk or bash?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why tagged bash and not awk?

Comment: @ctac_ I added the awk tag now. My initial idea was not to go specifically for awk, but for either awk or bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with (almost) what you have:

```
pax> echo 're1,1,a1e,a2e,AGT
re2,2,a1w,a2w,AGT
re3,3,a1t,a2t,ACGTCA
re12,4,b1e,b2e,ACGTACT' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3 = "pre3:"$3; $4 = "pre4:"$4; print}'

re1,1,pre3:a1e,pre4:a2e,AGT
re2,2,pre3:a1w,pre4:a2w,AGT
re3,3,pre3:a1t,pre4:a2t,ACGTCA
re12,4,pre3:b1e,pre4:b2e,ACGTACT
```

The `begin` block sets the input and output field separators, the two assignments massage fields 3 and 4, and the `print` outputs the modified line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `FS` to comma, not just `OFS`. There's a shortcut for setting `FS`, it's the `-F` option.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ $3="some_string" $3; $4 = "some_string" $4; print}' "$lookup_file"
```

Comment: `IFS` is a *bash* thing, not an awk thing. In `awk`, the input field separator is just `FS`. That doesn't mean your solution is wrong, just that you're using the wrong terminology.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks. Since I almost always use `-F`, I never have to deal with the actual variable name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @paxdiablo and @Barmar. I'm wondering, what if the string to add has single quotations? I've tried with `"\'"` but it doesnt work

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491064/1379826)
`awk -F"," -v quote="'" -v OFS="','" '{print quote $3,$4 quote}' $lookup_file`

Answer (score 1):

`awk`'s default action is to concatenate, so you can simply place strings next to each other and they'll be treated as one. 1 means true, so with no `{action}` it will assume "print". You can use Bash's Brace Expansion to assign multiple variables after the script.

```
awk '{$3 = "three" $3; $4 = "four" $4} 1' {O,}FS=,
```